# Rails app not responding to Postman requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman

My locally running rails app (on localhost:3000) responds to requests in the browser or from curl, but is not responding to requests from the desktop postman client, which immediately gives the generic "Could not get any response". Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: which `url` you are trying in `postman` and what kind of `response` you render on call of that `url`?

Comment: I'm just doing GET `localhost:3000`, though I've tried `0.0.0.0:3000` and `127.0.0.1:3000` for good measure. The result is the same for any of the routes. The response should be json, but the problem is the request is not hitting the server at all.

Comment: Make sure your rails server is running, and try whatever url in browser first, if it's works fine in browser then it should work on postman as well.

Comment: Provide some details of `routes.rb` and your controller action `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use NGROK. It provides you a tunnel which can easily be used with postman or anyother such service. Download the library from [here](https://ngrok.com/) and run the tunnel as

```
./ngrok http 3000
```

or you can use lvh.me:3000 if your request is from same machine.